# change array index to custom order php

Tags: php, arrays

i have an indexed array as follows

```
$item = array("one","two","three","four");
```

i need to change the index of this array with another array

```
$indexarray = array("2","0","3","1");
```

assign new intex to $item array like this,

```
one ---> 2
two ---> 0
three ---> 3
four ---> 1
```

so the needed result array should be like this

```
$item = array("two","four","one","three");
```

how can i achieve this , please help

Comment: Is this `array("2","0","3","1");` or `array(2,0,3,1);` ?

Answer (score 3):

```
Use:

$c=array_combine($indexarray ,$item );
print_r($c);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$indexarray = array("2","0","3","1");
$item = array("one","two","three","four");
$result=array_combine($indexarray ,$item );
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php    
    $item = array("one","two","three","four");
    $indexarray = array("2","0","3","1");
    $item_new=array();
    foreach($indexarray as $key=>$value)
    {
        $item_new[$key]=$item[$value];
    }
    $item=$item_new;
    print_r($item);
?>
```

Comment: The upper solutions are not giving the desired result as u written?

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Comment: as i understand @johnson wants to show the array "item" in order of values defined in array "indexarray". So first item array after updation will be $item[2], $item[0], $item[3], $item[1]. Let me know if i m wrong

Answer (score 0):

First combine both arrays

```
$item = array("one","two","three","four");
$indexArray = array("2","0","3","1");

$tempArray = array_combine($indexArray, $item);
```

Then sort the array

```
ksort($tempArray);
```